# Create nice looking Sudoku grid (that takes input) for mobile web app

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

I am looking for advice on creating a Sudoku Grid using JQuery Mobile. The grid needs to be filled in by the user, so I am using 81 select controls in a layout grid.

My goal is a grid that resizes nicely to the screen, but JQuery Mobile is wrapping the controls on narrow mobile devices. I can fix this by setting `.ui-select {width:30%;}`, but then of course they do not resize for larger screens.

Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/3njd5/1/ **(includes only the top third of the sudoku puzzle to keep it simple)**

As you can see, I have centering issues as well.

Does anyone know how to get it to resize & fill any size screen?

Is there a better framework for this?

Comment: I think this may actually be a valid use for an HTML <table>

Comment: Thanks, Diodeus. It's so simple I overlooked it :-)